# Passing Arabic Parameters through f:param in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, arabic, viewparams

We have a screen in our JSF PrimeFaces application that uses link tag to move to another page. There are 2 parameters that are passed to the second screen. When you hover the mouse over the link, you can see that the parameters are in Arabic. But other page receives the parameters in distorted form (this happens for Arabic parameter only. There is no problem for English). Is there any setting to enable proper passing of the Arabic parameters or I am missing something? Code is given below:

**First Screen:**

```
<p:link value="#{group.name}" outcome="contact">
<f:param name="id" value="#{group.id}" />
<f:param name="name" value="#{group.name}" />
</p:link>
```

**Second Screen:**
Getting the parameter

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{contact.groupID}"/>
    <f:viewParam name="name" value="#{contact.groupName}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

.
.
.
Code for Displaying the text

```
<h:outputText value="Name: #{contact.groupName}" style="float:left;"/>
```

I have debugged and found that the value passed to the bean of the second screen is distorted like Ø§ÙÙØ´Ø§Ø±.

Comment: Does it work if you use a plain jsf `h:link` counterpart (I don't think it is PrimeFaces related)

Comment: I just tried h:link and it didn't work either.

Comment: Then please change the code and the tagging accordingly since it is not PrimeFaces related

Comment: How will that solve the problem?

Comment: This is indeed not a JSF/PrimeFaces problem. You keep having the same problem irrespective of tag used. It's just a server configuration problem. The answer depends on the exact server make/version used.

Comment: Arabic is supported by the server and the link text is shown in Arabic as it should be. Are there any other settings for passing parameters?

Comment: As you neglected to tell the server make/version, I checked your other question and found out it was indeed Tomcat as I initially guessed. Now, check out the duplicate. Next time, please entirely answer the comments of those who want to help you or you won't be helped.

Comment: OK, it was my mistake then. Thanks!